# daily 200 reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I had earned 200 of daily reputation today 2nd time at Stack Overflow, now if any one upvote any of my question/answer or I earn some reputation for editing some post site is showing that into list and reducing my reputation from upvoted answers to maintain the 200.

If now some ne downvote my question/answer and it becomes the reason for reputation decrement, will it me maintained by the site even I reach to 200 reputation or not?

**EDIT** I have 21 or 22 upvotes on answers 3-6 edit and 3 downvoted removal that make my reputation about 220+ my question is if some one downvote my question/answers so that my reputation is reduced more than 10  then will it remain show the 200 or it will become 190 because of downvotes?

Comment: You have hit the daily reputation cap; you cannot earn more that 200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits. Accepted answer and bounties still count.

Comment: 200 is the max amount of rep you can gain from votes and edit approvals. If you have 20 upvotes for questions (200 rep) then a downvote (reducing to 198) then another upvote, that last upvote will give you only 2 reputation so you'll still be at 200. Another downvote, and that last upvote will be worth 4 rep etc.

Comment: @RalZarek this is what what looking wrong to me... dont you think it is wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in a single day.
If you get downvote after reaching rep cap, it will be deducted from your current reputation (200-2=198). It will not adjust with non-reputed upvotes (upvotes without reputation - after hitting rep. cap).

Comment: check my edit plz

Comment: What he's asking (I think) is if having gone over 200 when you receive a downvote does it deduct it from 200, or from the rep before it's capped at 200?